# Resteasy manual marshall/unmarshall of DTO

Tags: java, json, marshalling, resteasy, unmarshalling

I'm using resteasy 2.2.3.GA on jboss6 and have my resources working fine, serializing to/from JSON.

Marshalling/unmarshalling occurs by reflective magic on the resource method's arguments and and somehow involves the MessageBodyReader and MessageBodyWriter providers.

I would like to manually convert to and from a Json string to use in our debug framework.

```
public MyDTObject a(String json);
public String b(MyDTObject qwop);
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to how the underlying providers could be exposed?